# Unions of objects with prefix in Typescript

Tags: typescript

This seems embarrassingly simple but I have no solution. I cannot work out how to perform read operations on unions of objects.

Here is a simple union that works:

```
function unionAsType(a: string | number) {
   if (typeof a === 'string') {
      return a.indexOf('a'); // Typescript is happy because I have checked the type
   }
}
```

Here is a union with prefix on object which works:

```
function unionOfObjectsWithKeys(a: { type: 'str', str: string } | { type: 'num', num: number }) {
   if (a.type === 'str') {
      return a.str.indexOf('a'); // Typescript is happy because we have identified the type
   }
}
```

But if I have union without any prefixes I cannot access any parameters:

```
function unionAsObject(a: { str: string } | { num: number }) {
   if (typeof a.str === 'string') { // there doesn't appear to be a way of accessing str or num without casting

   }
}
```

In my mind the type of parameter a in unionAsObject when reading should be equivalent to:

```
interface {
  str?: string;
  num?: number;
}
```

The closest thing I can get to the actual result is to extract the type I want and pretend that Typescript thinks its optional, like this:

```
type Objects = { str: string } | { num: number };
function unionAsObject(a: Objects) {
   const maybeStr = a as Extract<Objects, { str: string }>;
   if (maybeStr.str !== undefined) {
      return maybeStr.str.indexOf('a');
   }
}
```

Does anyone know how to use plain objects in Typescript?

Comment: `if ('str' in a) {}`. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing

Comment: or use this for more complex cases https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates

Answer (score 2):

You can use `in` to check if the key is present in the type or not.

```
function unionAsObject(a: { str: string } | { num: number }) {
  if ('str' in a) {
    // Do someting
  }
}
```

Demo: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABOeYCCBnA8gIwFYCm0AFAIYBciA3ohlAE6V30xgDmiAvogD7WJgQAW0qChOAvS4BKagChEiGMETEA5MzVKkpWVQWLEAeiOIAInFpwhBWOwOc5nIA)

Answer (score 0):

In typescript, "unions" are variants, it is one OR another. However, if they share some field that will show at autocompletion.

```
type Objects = { str: string, shared: boolean } | { num: number, shared: boolean };
function unionAsObject(a: Objects) {
    a.shared
}
```

What you are looking for is "intersections":

```
type Objects = { str: string, shared: boolean } & { num: number, shared: boolean };
function unionAsObject(a: Objects) {
    a.shared
    a.str
    a.num
}
```